# Does the Perfect in addition to its perfect meaning also denotes perfective / imperfective / either meaning (in English and Spanish)?

Tags: english, spanish, perfect, imperfect

Just to note that I'm well aware as to the difference between the perfect and perfective aspects.

Up until recently I though that the Perfect aspect can denote (in addition to its perfect aspect meaning) also either a perfective or an imperfective aspect meaning (depending on the context).

However, lately I've stumbled upon these claims:

- [source](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/63): It's said that the **Perfect tenses in Spanish** denote a **perfective meaning**, while the **Conditional and Future** denote **imperfective meaning**.
- [source](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pret%C3%A9rito_perfecto_compuesto): It's said that the **Present Perfect in Spanish** denotes a **perfective meaning**.

My Questions:

1. Does the non-progressive **Present Perfect (Perfecto), Past Perfect (Pluscuamperfecto), Preterite Anterior (Pretérito Anterior) in Spanish** necessarily denote *perfective meaning* or can they also denote *imperfective meaning*?
2. Does the non-progressive **Perfect in English** necessarily denotes *perfective meaning* or can it also denote *imperfective meaning*?
3. Does the **Future (in English and Spanish)** and **Conditional (in Spanish)** necessarily denote *imperfective meaning* or can they also denote *perfective meaning*?
4. What about **Future Perfect and Conditional Perfect** which are a combination of 1,2 and 3 above?

Answer (score 1):

Since I have practically no knowledge of Spanish, I can answer only the English part.

First of all, the English Perfect is not an aspect. The two English aspects are Continuous (progressive) and Non-Continuous (non-progressive). A verb form cannot have two aspects at the same time, but English has several Perfect Continuous tenses and several Perfect Non-Continuous ones, that is, English can combine Continuous/Non-Continuous aspect with Perfect/Non-Perfect, and that is evidence that Perfect/Non-Perfect is not an aspect, look at it as just another category, perfectness, which is not an aspect.

Question 2. **No.** Some English verbs like sense perception ('see', 'hear', etc.) or likes/dislikes verbs ('love', 'hate', etc.) cannot be put into Continuous (progressive), so their Perfect forms can denote actions that are still in progress, e. g. 'I've loved you so much' which would correspond to the imperfective aspect, but at the same time that very sentence can denote an action/state that has already finished, and in this case it would correspond to the perfective aspect.

Question 3. If by **Future** you mean Future Indefinite aka Future Simple, the answer is also **No.** Have a look, 'Will you come to me?' in some situations can imply just one visit (tonight) which corresponds to the perfective aspect, but in some other situations it can imply multiple visits (every day) which corresponds to the imperfective aspect.

Question 4. Again **No.** That follows from the answers to questions 2 and 3, and also from the fact that *the very idea of the perfective and imperfective aspects is totally irrelevant for the English grammar and it absolutely does not correlate with the English verb category of perfect/non-perfect*.

Comment: There is a problem here with terms.  You appear to combine 'perfect' with 'preterite' to form a 2 bit tense, and keep separate a 1 bit 'progressive' aspect.  Many others consider a 1 bit 'preterite' tense, and 2 aspect bits for 'perfect' and 'progressive'.  Each binary feature of a verb could properly be called an aspect, and no pairings should be given preference without a good reason.

Comment: @amI - If a language has aspects, this means that _every_ verb is in this or that aspect, it is impossible for a verb in a tense not to have an aspect. Every English tense is at least 3 bit: 1. time (present or past or future or future-in-the-past, yeah, this bit is not binary, but quaternary), 2. aspect (progressive or non-progressive), 3. perfectness (perfect or non-perfect).

Comment: Adding 'future' to 'tense' is another problem.  Does tense refer to the 'preterite' bit, or does it include the perfect, progressive and hypothetical bits, or does it exclude the progressive bit?  Does 'simple' mean neither perfect nor progressive, or just not progressive?  I see people using all these scenarios, and it makes the terms ambiguous.

Comment: @amI - I see it this way: "tense" is the combination of time (present, or past, or future, or future-in-the-past), aspect (progressive or non-progressive), and perfectness (perfect or non-perfect). "Simple" means "non-progressive non-perfect". "Present Perfect" means "present time non-progressive perfect" and "Present Continuous" means "present time progressive non-perfect", etc.

Comment: Then I again simply warn you:  The Wikipedia entry on grammatical aspect states that 'future' is not part of 'tense', and 'perfect' is an 'aspect'.  Our systems may be self-consistent, but if the definitions of terms are not universal then communication will be difficult.

Comment: @amI - You can well rely on Wiki and ask no one else. But if you'd like to hear an alternative point of view, then you come here, don't you?

Comment: Please don't be smarmy.  I just want terms that I can use with precision.  'Simple' combines (the lack of) 'perfect' and 'progressive', so we have created a pairing.  What is the name of that pair, if not 'aspect'?  Why would you call only the progressive bit aspect, when that bit already has a name (=progressive)?

Answer (score 0):

As for Spanish:

1. **Perfecto** is usually perfective, but in some situations an imperfective reading is also possible. For example:

> He vivido allí durante toda mi vida.

It may (but does not have to) mean that you still live there. I think **pluscuamperfecto** may have imperfective reading, too. I'm not sure about **pretérito anterior**, a native Spanish speaker would need to comment on it.

3. **Futuro simple** may have a perfective meaning. [Here](http://gredos.usal.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10366/110664/DFM_Fidalgo_Enriquez_FJ_LaExpresion.pdf?sequence=1) is an example (p. 97):

> Aunque vendrá mañana no lo veré, moriré antes.

The verb *moriré* is clearly perfective here.

4. Both aspects are possible in **futuro perfecto**. [Here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/examples-of-future-perfect-tense-es.html) are some examples:

> En septiembre habré vivido aquí durante ocho años.

The only sensible interpretation I can see is that the action of "living here" will still be ongoing as of September, so its aspect is imperfective. But:

> Habremos vuelto a casa antes de las cinco horas.

The action of "returning" will be completed by five o'clock, so it has a perfective aspect.